# How to switch different xaml for different orientation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, orientation

I know how to show a content page but how do I select the right layout based on the orientation. I wanted to write xaml files: one for vertical orientation and other one for horizontal orientation. Is it possible to switch the xaml file when orientation changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Xamarin.Forms does not offer any native events for notifying your app
>   of orientation changes in shared code. However, the SizeChanged event
>   of the Page fires when either the width or height of the Page changes.
>   When the width of the Page is greater than the height, the device is
>   in landscape mode.

```cs
protected override void OnSizeAllocated (double width, double height){
    base.OnSizeAllocated (width, height);
    if (width != this.width || height != this.height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        if (width > height) {
            // landscape
        } else {
            // portrait
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can change programmatically the content of your page to a new content base on the orientation.

```cs
Content = // new content here.
```

With some patient you could try to use the same XAML but only changing the orientation of some views, example [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation/#Responsive_Layout).

Source [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation/).

Comment: Without looking at the implementation its hard to answer that. But when you rotate the screen (at least in android) the views must be created and draw again. So its almost the same cost to create a new view or rotate the existing one. In your case i guess the best to do is what is more easy for you.

Comment: Hmm.. I have a interface which has left panel, center area for drawing and a right panel in landscape mode and top panel, center, and bottom for portrait mode. Each of the panel, has 5 image buttons. What is the best practice of doing it. Make as a Content View or Content Page.

Comment: This comment section is getting too big i will remove old comments from it, please do the same. So for your first content view in XAML you will have some code behind. In your other content view you will need a very similar if not equal code behind. For that i suggest to create a different class that has de code behind and use that same class in your content views.

Comment: If we have two separate code behind but the functionality are the same. I would be duplicate the inner code. Sorry if I have any misunderstand.

Comment: Since the functionality is the and the inner code is the same to, I suggested you to pick that code, put it in a separate class and use that class in your inner code.

Comment: I see what you mean